# how to add search range input into the datatable

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

```html
<span>Product:</span>
<input type="text" name="product" class="form-control input-sm">
<span>Code:</span>
<input type="text" name="code" class="form-control input-sm">
**<span>Min Price:</span>
<input type="text" name="price" class="form-control input-sm">**
```

How to search range of the price in input like 0-100 100-500 500-1000 or using select.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  // Map inputs with columns (nth-child(X)) 
  var inputMapper = {
    "product": 1,
    "code": 2,
    "price": 3
  };
  $("input").on("input", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var val = $this.val();
    var key = $this.attr("name");
    dtInstance.columns(inputMapper[key] - 1).search(val).draw();
  });
});
```

Comment: If that is your code, can you add it to the original post?

Comment: Did you ever find it out? I can see your use of `dtInstance` is a little bit wrong, it should (normally) be  `dtInstance.DataTable.columns(inputMapper[key] - 1).search(val).draw();`...